# Missing characters using echo in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I tried to write a shell script that runs commands using a specific like `sudo su - user` so I used `sudo -H -u user bash -c` and all is working well except some echo commands.

This is not working and I can't solve it

```
sudo -H -u mailq bash -c "cd /var/www/html; echo -e \"
#!/bin/bash

NAME=\"user\"
DIR=/var/www/html    
cd \$DIR
\" > start"
```

it prints like

```
#!/bin/bash


NAME=user
DIR=/var/www/html    
cd
```

Comment: What's your end goal here ? It's still unclear what you are trying to achieve !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely clear what OP is asking, but there seems to be an issue with double and single quotes in the `bash -c` arguments.

```
$ sudo -H -u mailq bash -c "cd /var/www/html; echo ' 
#!/bin/bash

NAME=\"user\"
DIR=\"/var/www/html\"    
cd \$DIR
'>~/start"
```

Output will be written to `~/start`.

```
$ cat ~/start 

#!/bin/bash

NAME="user"
DIR="/var/www/html"    
cd $DIR
```

Note, as @Charles_Duffy points out, this kinda script insertion/execution can be hazardous and difficult to debug.

Comment: This works for the data at hand, but `echo -e` is by no means a good practice.

Comment: -e for escaping the backslash

Comment: @A.Raouf, you're mistaken if you think it's needed for that purpose. More to the point, `echo -e` **isn't even guaranteed to work at all**. See [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), and note that bash's `echo` conforms to the letter of that spec when both `posix` and `xpg_echo` runtime options are enabled.

Comment: @A.Raouf, ...compare `echo "$PWD"` and `echo "\$PWD"` -- you'll see they have two different results even with no `-e`.

Answer (score 2):

Compare your original implementation to the following:

```
sudo -H -u mailq sh -c 'cat >"$1"' _ /var/www/html/start <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
NAME=user
DIR=/var/www/html
cd "$DIR"
EOF
```

Because `<<'EOF'` has the heredoc quoted, all contents within are literal. There's no need to escape `\$DIR` to prevent it from being immediately evaluated.

Comment: BTW -- I stand by this as being more representative of reliable and portable practices than either the OP's original code or the current accepted answer.